# Como verificar variável tem valores?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho uma função que realiza um select no banco:

```
function selectIdProdutos($id){
    $banco = abrirBanco();
    $sql = " SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = ".$id;
    $resultado = $banco->query($sql);
    $banco->close();
    $produto = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
    return $produto;
}
```

Porém, quando não existe registros no banco ele retorna:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: produtos in `C:\xampp\htdocs\despesas\despesas\registra_produto.php on line 63`

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\despesas\despesas\consulta_produtos.php on line 86
```

Para mostrar os produtos eu utilizo:

```
<tbody>
                <?php

                foreach($grupo as $produtos){ ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td><?=$produtos["descricao"]?> </td>
                        <td>R$<?=$produtos["custo"]?></td>
                        <td>R$<?=$produtos["preco_venda"]?></td>
                        <td> <?php
                            if($produtos["fg_ativo"] == '1'){
                                $produtos["fg_ativo"] = "Ativo";
                            }
                            else{
                                $produtos["fg_ativo"] = "Inativo";
                            }
                        ?>
                        <?=$produtos["fg_ativo"]?> </td>
                        <td>

                            <form name="alterar" action="alterar_produtos.php" method="POST">
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value= <?=$produtos["id"]?> />
                                <input type="submit" value="Editar" name="editar" class="btn btn-default">
                            </form>

                        </td>
                        <td>

                            <form name="excluir" action="registra_produto.php" method="POST">

                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$produtos["id"]?> " />
                                <input type="hidden" name="acao" value="excluir" />
                                <input type="submit" value="Excluir" name="excluir" class="btn btn-default" />

                            </form>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <script>
                        function msgSucesso(){
                            alert('Produto excluido com sucesso');
                        }
                    </script>


                <?php

                }

                ?>
```

Como eu posso tratar isso?

Comment: Você pode testar a variável utilizando a condição !empty - Função empty Determina se uma variável é considerada vazia. Uma variável é considerada vazia se não existir ou seu valor é igual FALSE. A função empty() não gera um aviso se a variável não existir.

Comment: Coloque a parte do código onde vc seta o valor da variável produtos
os erros que esta dando é referente a variável não esta definida e não referente aos seus valores

Comment: Minha resposta foi util nesta sua pergunta?

Comment: O erro informa que a variavel $produtos não foi definida. E pelo exemplo de codigo ela realmente não existe. A que existe é $produto.

Answer (score -1):

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso:

Tem uma função do php que se chama [isset()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) ela nos ajuda a verificar se a `variavel` por `parametro` está `setada`, ou contem algum valor. Por Ex:

```
if(isset($_POST['nome'])){
   $nome = $_POST['nome'];
}else{
   $nome = '';
}
```

> ou seja se tiver valor em nome, atribui a variavel nome, se não
>   coloque-a como vazio.

outra maneira é usando a Função [empty](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php) (click para ver a documentação).

Determina se uma variável é considerada vazia. Uma variável é considerada vazia se não existir ou seu valor é igual FALSE. A função empty() não gera um aviso se a variável não existir.

por exemplo:

```
if(empty($_POST['nome'])){
    $nome = 'vazio';
}else{
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
}
```

> ou seja se nome for vazio, atribui vazio a variavel nome, se não
>   coloque-a o valor de nome.

Lembrando que todas essas funções você pode atribuir o operador ternário `!` para fazer ao contrario dentro de um if. por exemplo:

```
  if(!isset()) // se nao tiver setado

  if(!empty()) // se nao tiver vazio
```